# Java : implementing a template interface several time (with different class parameter)

Tags: java, android

I'm facing the following issue in a personnal project using java (I'm used to c++ but very novice in java). This is an application for Android.

Basically I have an abstract template class and 2 other child classes using different class parameter (String and LocationItem)

I wanted to implement both interface in my main class LocalizerService and was surprised java complains I'm trying to add the same interface.

Error raised in Android studio is the following :

error: OnBufferInteractionListener cannot be inherited with different arguments: java.lang.String and com.ogtest.localizer.tools.LocationItem

I guess it is a nogo message, but do you think there is an alternate (and nice) way to achieve similar feature ? And more could you explain why java cannot differentiate the 2 interfaces ?

Many thanks.

Sample code (simplified as far as possible) :

```
public abstract class BufferArray<E> {

    public interface OnBufferInteractionListener<E> {
        void onPush(E item);
        void onRemove(E item);
    }
    private OnBufferInteractionListener<E> mBufferInteractionListener;
    public void setOnBufferInteractionListener(OnBufferInteractionListener<E> callback) {
        this.mBufferInteractionListener = callback;
    }

....

}

public class LogBuffer extends BufferArray<String> {
....
}

public class LocationBuffer extends BufferArray<LocationItem>{
....
}


public class LocaLizerService extends Service implements LogBuffer.OnBufferInteractionListener<String>,
                                                         LocationBuffer.OnBufferInteractionListener<LocationItem>  {

    /* callbacks */
    public void onPush(LocationItem item) { ....  }
    public void onRemove(LocationItem item) { .... }
    public void onPush(String item) { ....  }
    public void onRemove(String item) { .... }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        LOGBuffer = new LogBuffer();
        LOGBuffer.setOnBufferInteractionListener(LocaLizerService.this);
        GPSBuffer = new LocationBuffer();
        GPSBuffer.setOnBufferInteractionListener(LocaLizerService.this);
        ...
    }

....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that in some cases the compiler could not check, which method to call or which member to store the value in.

Imagine a set of types that are related by inheritance: MyString, MyStringLog extends String, MyTextLog extends MyStringLog,...
If you then define the Log*Buffers that extend the BufferArray using the related types, you get classes, that may accept different input types. At least the classes that are defined by the more generic types like MyString in this example.

And if you then define your LocalizerService class using two or more of these Log*Buffers, your compiler and run time system must panic: you have a set of methods and fields, which have basically the same signature/type for several input types. But overloading says, the signature must be different. And the fields must be unique.

Although the above example is not the case in your example, it may come true later on.... so the compiler complains about this.